# Proving a right triangle with an altitude have two similar triangles

Tags: geometry

> Q. Create a right triangle and draw an altitude to the hypotenuse.
>   When dragging the points of the right triangle, noticed that the two
>   smaller triangles that are formed within the larger right triangle
>   appear to always be similar to each other, and more surprisingly, seem
>   to always be similar to the big triangle. How do you prove it?

I am having a hard time proving this because I was taught that if we want to prove triangles similar we need two angles but I can only find one.

Let ABC be a right triangle with altitude AD. I need to show triangle ADB and ADC are similar. ADB and ADC are right angles so they are equal to each other.

Any idea how to get the 2nd angle?

Comment: It is easiest to show $ABC$ and $ABD$ are similar. They share an angle at $B$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether you add angles DAC to BAD or ACD, the result ( sum total) is same, equal to  90 degrees. So they are equal.

$$ \angle BAD = \angle ACD $$

similarly

$$ \angle DBA=  \angle DAC $$

You said

$$ \angle ADB = \angle CDA = 90^{0} $$

Done.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

1)$ABC$ and $ABD$ have a right angle and a common angle in $B$.

2)$ABC$ and $ACD$ have a right angle and a common angle in $C$.